# How can I find package name of some application(android platform)? ex-com.facebook.katana

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to know some application package name for open that from my own application

Comment: please explain more, you need to get the package name of all installed apps?

Comment: @Janidu does any answer below reply to your question?

Comment: I need open Termius app in my android application

Comment: that is ssh handling applicaiton

Answer (score 0):

you can download some package manager app, it can shows the package names of apps that installed in your device.
Or you can run the app the package name of which you want to know and use ADB commands to get the package name of runned app's activity.

Comment: i mean in android platform

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to use `adb` to list the installed apps by package names and filter it out based on the app's name you're looking for:

```
adb shell pm list packages | grep facebook
```

(if you're on a linux/macOS)

Comment: android platform any solution?